# Need of a better condition for a socket timeout

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am a beginner in Python and the task is to establish a client server communication using UDP frames over the network.
I am using multithreading here, to make sure that the *SendData* functionality and *ReceiveData* functionality executes in parallel.

Also made use of a LiFo Queue- sendMessageQueue

Over the network, the messages transmitted are customized.

```
def frameMessage(i):
        text='Hello'
        ping=i
        ID ="{:02d}".format(ping)
        sendlength = len(text) 
        sendLengthModified ="{:05d}".format(sendlength)
        frame_message = '<' + str(ID) +str(sendLengthModified) + text 
        remainingBytes = c_length_byte-(len(frame_message)-1)
        for i in range(0, remainingBytes):
            if(len(frame_message)==(c_length_byte-1)):
                break
            frame_message += str(i)
        frame=frame_message+'>'
        #print(frame)
        return frame,I
```

The SendData functionality

```
def SendInfiniteData():
        
        for i in range (100):
            frame ,ID=frameMessage(i)
            frame_message_in_Bytes =    bytes(frame,'utf-8')
            if i == 0:
                         start_ref=timer()
            start =timer()
            #print(frame_message_in_Bytes)
            sendMessageQueue.put((frame_message_in_Bytes,start,start_ref))
            framesList.append(frame_message_in_Bytes)            
            client_socket.sendto(frame_message_in_Bytes, addr)
            event.set()
            time.sleep(c_tick_ms/1000)
            if(i==99):
             i=0
             while(True):
                 SendIData(start_ref) // this is a specific requirement for continous transmission
```

The receiveData funcitonality

```
def ReceiveInfiniteData():
          #time.sleep(1/1000000000000)
          while (sendMessageQueue):
             
             try:   
              
                  data, server = client_socket.recvfrom(2048) 
                  revisedData=data[:3]+data[8:13]+data[14:]
                  buffer=sendMessageQueue.get()
                  if(revisedData==buffer[0]):
                      stop=timer()
                      elapsed_ms=(stop - buffer[1])*1000
                  
                      Instance=buffer[1]-buffer[2]
                
                      print('Replying from', IP +' Bytes:',str(c_length_byte) + ' Time:'+f' {elapsed_ms:.10f} ms' + ' ID: '+str(data.decode('utf-8')[1:3])+ ' Instance: '+f' {Instance:.2f}s')
                      

             except socket.timeout:
                      if(th.is_alive()):
                          print('REQUEST TIMED OUT at Instance: '+f' {Instance:.2f}s')
```

The problem I face is that, even though the communication is happening correctly, i get a socket timeout error.
The timeout code is

```
client_socket.settimeout(c_tick_ms/1000) // this is a command line program..
```

The output appears as below

```
Replying from 169.254.149.51 Bytes: 600 Time: 2.7648000000 ms ID: 00 Instance:  0.00s
REQUEST TIMED OUT at  Instance:  0.00 seconds
Replying from 169.254.149.51 Bytes: 600 Time: 3.6895000000 ms ID: 01 Instance:  0.50s
REQUEST TIMED OUT at  Instance:  0.50 seconds
Replying from 169.254.149.51 Bytes: 600 Time: 2.8836000000 ms ID: 02 Instance:  1.00s
REQUEST TIMED OUT at  Instance:  1.00 seconds
Replying from 169.254.149.51 Bytes: 600 Time: 2.6886000000 ms ID: 03 Instance:  1.50s
REQUEST TIMED OUT at  Instance:  1.50 seconds
Replying from 169.254.149.51 Bytes: 600 Time: 3.7843000000 ms ID: 04 Instance:  2.01s
Replying from 169.254.149.51 Bytes: 600 Time: 2.5657000000 ms ID: 05 Instance:  2.51s
REQUEST TIMED OUT at  Instance:  2.51 seconds
Replying from 169.254.149.51 Bytes: 600 Time: 2.8497000000 ms ID: 06 Instance:  3.01s
REQUEST TIMED OUT at  Instance:  3.01 seconds
```

When there is a successful communication, there should not be a timeout error. I am struggling to put a condition for the timeout statement. Although i have a thought of monitoring the *revisedData* for its change in contents, I do not understand how to do it.

Please, any ideas or suggestions would help

Comment: Why does your code print "REPLYING" when it isn't replying? Why does it print "REQUEST TIMED OUT" when you get a *read* timeout? Why have you set a 500ms timeout if you're trying to receive infinitely?Where is the code that sets the timeout? What is the application protocol? If this is a request/response protocol why are there two threads?

Comment: So basically the requirement is to have a command line program (similar to a ping program )over a LiFi Network. We made use of UDP protocol. On the command line if we type 'run P_Buffer 169.254.149.51 -tick 50 -l 600 -t' , here the 50 represents the frequency at which ping happens in milliseconds, -t would mean the infinite communication. and 600 would be the number of bytes transferred on each ping. The reason why i used multithreading is.. I wanted tp have a parallel execution of senddata and receivedata functions.

Comment: I have imported the socket class and have given the timeout to be the same as the frequency(50ms)  using socket.setTimeout(). Why i have a timeout is because we cannot wait infinitely for a packet, since the transfer needs to be quick, if there is a miss in transmission, it should come as Request timed out

Comment: What I se eis that, the timeout functionality gets executed inspite of having the data which is being received.. The way it should work is I should not be getting the timeout error when there is a successful ping. I am not able to find a solution